# How can i store the registration details in local storage without overwriting it the next time?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So basically i have a registration form and everytime the user registers, i store their data in HTML local storage, but i want the data to look like this for example:
user| [{"username":"Maximillian","password":"whatever","address":""whatever".... and so on. So far i have this code but i am confused with why it doesn't work the way i want it to. And how do i make sure that when another person registers, their details does not overwrite the current register details already on local storage?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't store passwords in clear text anywhere. Perhaps create temporary access hashes that can be deleted and checked server side

Comment: i am not using server side... i'm just wondering how i would do what i am looking for

Comment: I think the point here I was trying to make is that this is ethically bad and I'd feel uncomfortable helping you. But I'm sure someone will.

Comment: hmm okay no worries... i'm just learning so i'm not really gonna go public with my website, just testing the basics out which is why i am asking for this kind of help, so if you can help, please don't feel uncomfortable in that way, i assure you in that

Comment: @Dominik It's obviously a bad practice but I don't see why it would be ethically bad. It would always be local to the user's computer, so the only way it could be leaked is if the user had a virus, and then that would be a bigger problem.

Comment: Or if you share your computer. But my problem doesn't lay with where it's stored but how it's stored. Clear text means you can retrieve the password and if you've reused your password somewhere else lose access there too. It's never a good idea.

Comment: I would definitely recommend hashing passwords, but I don't see a problem if this website *will never* be public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store an array of the users. For example:

```
var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) || [];
var userData = [{Username:document.getElementById("UserName").value},
{Email:document.getElementById("EmailAddress").value},
{Password:document.getElementById("PassWord").value},
{Address:document.getElementById("Address1").value},
{Phone:document.getElementById("PhoneNumber").value}];

users.push(userData);
localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(users));
```

Then access the users as such:

```
var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) || [];
users.forEach(console.log);
users[0];
users[1];
[etc.]
```

Comment: Submitting two registration data for users will be performed through the `users.push` method as specified in the first code block. By pushing the data into the array, you won't be overwriting the data of another user.

The second code block just shows an example of how to parse the data from local storage into a JSON array that you can use, and how to access user elements from that array.

Comment: @A.Adams Have you copied my code correctly? It works as intended for me: https://i.imgur.com/kgXJ4xa.png

Comment: So what you are saying is i put that in the console log and it should show me the other user's details??

Comment: I put that in the console log but can only see the first user details submitted in the register form and not two. This is annoying me haha

Comment: @A.Adams Your code must be overriding the Users array somewhere else. Both of these users are registered on the same computer and browser, right?